# PowerBi Dashboard Design

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, sharepoint-online, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to connect a SharePoint list to Power BI, but it takes a long time to expand the columns and load data to the dashboard. It took more than 5 hours to load 450MB of data.

This is the Query I have written,

```
let
Source = SharePoint.Tables("XXX/", [ApiVersion = 15]),
#"YYY" = Source{[Id="YYY"]}[Items],
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"YYY",{{"ID", "ID.1"}}),
#"Expanded NameofGMApprover2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "NameofGMApprover2", {"Title"}, {"NameofGMApprover2.Title"}),
#"Expanded NameofHODApprover2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded NameofGMApprover2", "NameofHODApprover2", {"Title"}, {"NameofHODApprover2.Title"}),
#"Expanded NameofExecutive2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded NameofHODApprover2", "NameofExecutive2", {"Title"}, {"NameofExecutive2.Title"}),
#"Expanded AssignInvoice" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded NameofExecutive2", "AssignInvoice", {"Title"}, {"AssignInvoice.Title"}),
#"Expanded NameofApprover2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded AssignInvoice", "NameofApprover2", {"Title"}, {"NameofApprover2.Title"}),
#"Expanded NameofApprover1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded NameofApprover2", "NameofApprover1", {"Title"}, {"NameofApprover1.Title"}),
#"Expanded NameofExecutive" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded NameofApprover1", "NameofExecutive", {"Title"}, {"NameofExecutive.Title"}),
#"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Status", each if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Operator Approval" then [NameofExecutive.Title] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Additional Operator Approval" then [NameofExecutive2.Title] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending HOD Approval" then [NameofApprover1.Title] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending for Additional HOD Approval" then [NameofHODApprover2.Title] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending GM/DR Approval" then [NameofApprover2.Title] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending for Additional GM/DR Approval" then [NameofGMApprover2] else if [OverAllStatus.Title] = "Assign Invoice" then [AssignInvoice.Title] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Invoice Booking" then [AssignInvoice.Title] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending with Account Payable Team" then "Accounts Team" else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Accounts Team Assignment" then "Accounts Team" else if [OverAllStatus] = "Invoice Booked" then "Finished Workflow" else if [OverAllStatus] = "Rejected" then "Rejected " else if [OverAllStatus] = "Finish Workflow" then "Finish Workflow" else "  "),
#"Added Conditional Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "Assigned Date ", each if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Operator Approval" then [ExecutiveAssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Additional Operator Approval" then [Executive2AssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending HOD Approval" then [HODAssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending for Additional HOD Approval" then [HOD2AssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending GM/DR Approval" then [GMAssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending for Additional GM/DR Approval" then [GM2AssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Assign Invoice" then [BookingAssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Invoice Booking" then [BookingAssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending with Account Payable " then [APTeamAssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Accounts Team Assignment" then [APTeamAssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Finish Workflow" then [Modified] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Rejected" then [Modified] else "    "),
#"Added Conditional Column2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column1", "Currency Value", each if [InvoiceCurrency] = "USD" then 3.67 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "EURO" then 4.25 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "SAR" then 0.981 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "OMR" then 9.55 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "BHD" then 9.75 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "GBP" then 4.92 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "KWD" then 12.12 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "QAR" then 1.01 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "YEN" then 0.032 else if [InvoiceCurrency] = "ZAR" then 0.24 else 1),
#"Added Conditional Column3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column2", "Pending Updated Date", each if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Operator Approval" then [ExecutiveAssignedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Additional Operator Approval" then [ExecutiveUpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending HOD Approval" then [HODUpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending for Additional HOD Approval" then [HOD2UpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending GM/DR Approval" then [GMUpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Assign Invoice" then [BookingUpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Invoice Booking" then [BookingUpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending with Account Payable Team" then [APTeamUpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending Accounts Team Assignment" then [APTeamUpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Pending for Additional GM/DR Approval" then [GM2UpdatedDate] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Finish Workflow" then [Modified] else if [OverAllStatus] = "Rejected" then [Modified] else "  "),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Added Conditional Column3", "Created", "Created - Copy"),
#"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Assigned Date ", "Assigned Date  - Copy"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column1",{{"Assigned Date ", type datetime}}),
#"Extracted Date" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Created - Copy", DateTime.Date, type date}}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Date",{{"Assigned Date  - Copy", type date}}),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Created - Copy", "Created - Date"}, {"Assigned Date  - Copy", "Assigned - Date"}}),
#"Duplicated Column2" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Created - Date", "Created - Date - Copy"),
#"Duplicated Column3" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Column2", "Assigned - Date", "Assigned - Date - Copy"),
#"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column3",{{"Created - Date - Copy", "Created - Date - Text"}, {"Assigned - Date - Copy", "Assigned - Date - Text"}}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns2",{{"InvoiceApprovalWorkflow", type any}}),
#"Expanded InvoiceApprovalWorkflow" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Changed Type2", "InvoiceApprovalWorkflow", {"Url"}, {"InvoiceApprovalWorkflow.Url"}),
#"Duplicated Column4" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Expanded InvoiceApprovalWorkflow", "Pending Updated Date", "Pending Updated Date - Copy"),
#"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column4",{{"Pending Updated Date - Copy", "Pending Updated  - date"}}),
#"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns3",{{"Pending Updated  - date", type date}}),
#"Renamed Columns4" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type3",{{"Status", "Pending WIth"}})
```

in
#"Renamed Columns4"

Comment: Did you verify how long its takes without expanding/adding a column? 
Can You skip some of your columns/rows?

Comment: With out expanding and not adding any columns it takes nearly one and half hrs. even though i removed the not needed columns it takes much time data source is on Live. Nearly 800MB of data i have now 2)whether i have to rewrite the measures for connecting new datasource @msta42a

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try with joins instead of expanding each column, that probably improve the performance as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/optimize-expanding-table-columns

Other thing you can try is make a initial download, make a query that downloads all the data in your tables in a DataFlow (PowerBi) or a CSV (Excel) without joining them, just the plain tables.

Then on PowerBi make a query pointing to that source and make your joins. With this way you can even make some parameters tables and use them instead of your conditional columns.